# Weighted averages with fractions instead of frequencies?

Tags: statistics

So I have a bunch of scores 0-100 and a two sets of weights, the frequency which is the number of people in the sample with an average score among those people. Then I have another value that is the fraction of people in that group for the given score. An example may look like this:

```
"Average Score of sample"    "Number of people in sample"    "Subset of people in sample"
65                           8                            .75
87                           4                            1.0
34                           1                            1.0
50                           3                            .33333
72                           9                            .66666
```

Here is a link to a Google spreadsheet that provides three examples of the calculations in questions on a set N=100:
[Spreadsheet Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ai9OXRu1UgWCdC1mbmkxQnFSSDREY1hPRTZRWnVMaGc&usp=sharing)

So my question is, on a larger sample size, can I use the fraction as the weight(Column M) and still expect similar results to the Frequency * Fraction (Column N) weighting approach? How could I go about analyzing data to find a bias between the two approaches?

Thanks for your insight! If any additional information is needed please let me know!

Comment: By "Group" do you mean "Sample"?  By "Subset of people in group" do you mean "Number of people in the sample with exactly the given score?"  "at least the given score"?  Is the given score the average score or some secret number?

Comment: Yes the group is a sample, and the subset is the simply a smaller sample of the same group. The score is an average score of the individuals scores. Sorry for not being clear!